# Dart - make long running synchronous function asynchronous

Tags: dart

I have a function that might take a few seconds to execute, and it is synchronous. Does:

```dart
String slowFunction() { ... }
...
Future<String>(() => slowFunction());
```

change it to asynchronous?

If I need its result in the next step, does this code make sense?

```dart
Future<void> anotherFunction() async {
  // other async calls with Futures and await
  ...
  final result = await Future<String>(() => slowFunction());
  print(result);
  ...
  // do something else with result
}
```

Seems kind of strange to create a `Future` only to immediately `await` on it. Should I just call the function? I guess it kind of 'yields' and allows other code to be executed before, but does such code have any use?

Comment: You can use `Completer`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no point in making a process that is inherently synchronous and dressing it up as an asynchronous one. This is due to how asynchronicity (more generally referred to as "concurrency") works, not just in Dart but in general. Concurrency is just a programming trick to make multiple operations run interleaved with each other in the same thread, giving the illusion of true parallelism (which is where different threads or processes run simultaneously). This allows processes that would normally block while waiting for a resource to be put off until later as the program carries on with other things.

If you were to take a synchronous process that blocks *due to work being actively done*, either the program will block anyway as the "async" code executes just as it would otherwise do or the program will block just as long but at a later time. Either way, you are still blocking your program with a long-running process.

Take the following for example, which is what you ask: take a long-running synchronous workload and wrap it in a `Future`, thus making it "asynchronous":

```dart
Future<String> slowFunction() async { 
  // Simulate a long-running synchronous operation
  int counter = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {
    counter++;
  }

  // Return the "asynchronous" result
  return counter.toString();
}

...

String result = await slowFunction();
```

In normal concurrency, this will put `slowFunction` in the async queue. The next time the program has some downtime (in between UI draw calls, for example) it will pull that function out of the queue and process it. And *that's* when it will block for however many seconds while the function executes.

In Dart, though, it works slightly differently. `slowFunction` may be marked as `async`, but because it doesn't actually `await` anything, Dart will attempt to run it synchronously anyway, defeating the whole purpose. You needn't have bothered wrapping it in a `Future` in the first place.

You have two options here if you want to break up the operation of your synchronous function. Either you have to break it up into distinct operations that you can `await` between (which is itself a somewhat complicated process, isn't always possible, and is generally a good source of code smell), or you offload the function to a separate thread altogether, employing *parallelism* rather than mere *concurrency*.

Dart is single-threaded, but it can be multi-processed through the use of isolates. (An isolate is Dart's name for a child process and is as close to true multithreading that you can get in Dart.) By wrapping your function in an `Isolate`, you can run the work on an entirely separate process. That way, if that process blocks for 2-3 seconds, it won't affect the bulk of your app at all.

There is a catch, though. Because isolates are completely different processes, there is no sharing of memory whatsoever. That means any data that the isolate has access to has to be manually passed in through the use of "ports", namely `SendPort` and `ReceivePort`. This naturally makes isolate programming a bit of a pain, but in exchange, you won't run into things like your program having race conditions or getting deadlocked. (Because of shared memory problems, at least. Strictly speaking, there are plenty of other ways to get deadlocks and race conditions.)

Using an `Isolate` works like so:

```dart
// main process

void createIsolate() async {
  ReceivePort isolateToMain = ReceivePort();

  isolateToMain.listen((data) {
    // Listen for data passed back to the main process
  });

  Isolate myIsolateInstance = await Isolate.spawn(myIsolate, isolateToMain.sendPort);
}

// isolate process

void myIsolate(SendPort mainToIsolate) {
  final result = slowFunction();
  mainToIsolate.send(result);
}
```

Comment: Exactly, I was thinking of a method that takes 50 ms it calls 5 other sync methods, 10 ms each, to do its job. If it is called synchronously, it will just block the isolate for 50 ms, but if I make it async, and wrap all of the 5 inner methods in a Future + await as in my question, would this make sense? It would allow other code to be executed in between these, naturally sync, calls?

Comment: Yeah, I know about isolates and can use them successfully, but I kind of don't understand Futures as much as I would, yet, hence the question.

Comment: @wujek That falls under paragraphs 2 and 5, where if you are marking a method as `async` but it doesn't actually do any asynchronous operation, Dart will still run it asynchronously. There is a way to force it to do so, but it is generally more trouble than it's worth (and they usually have a bit of a code smell about them anyway).

Comment: @wujek And it's alright if it blocks the isolate because that isolate is separate from the rest of your app. That's the whole reason why isolates exist, so you can run blocking functions without it affecting the performance of the rest of your program.

Comment: Nice, but when you say 'hard locked', do you mean deadlock?

Comment: @BenB Yes, deadlocked. I've been watching some speedruns lately and had that terminology in my head.

Answer (score 5):

> I have a function that might take a few seconds to execute, and it is synchronous. Does:
>
> ```dart
> String slowFunction() { ... }
> ...
> Future<String>(() => slowFunction());
> ```
>
> change it to asynchronous?

Simply returning a `Future` will not make your function asynchronous in the way that you probably want.

When you call an asynchronous function, as much of it as possible will be executed *synchronously*.  That is, the function will execute synchronously until it reaches the first `await` (i.e., until it returns a `Future`).  Since a Dart isolate is single-threaded, if you want other work to be able to occur concurrently with your long-running operation, `slowFunction` would internally need to use `await` (which is syntactic sugar for creating `Future.then()` callbacks) to allow execution to yield.

Consider the following code:

```dart
Future<void> longRunningOperation1() async {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i += 1) {
    if (i % 10000000 == 0) {
      print('longRunningOperation1: $i');
    }
  }
}

Future<void> longRunningOperation2() async {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i += 1) {
    if (i % 10000000 == 0) {
      print('longRunningOperation2: $i');
    }
  }
}

Future<void> main() async {
  await Future.wait([longRunningOperation1(), longRunningOperation2()]);
}
```

You will see that `longRunningOperation1` and `longRunningOperation2` never overlap; one always runs to completion before the other one starts.  To allow the operations to overlap with minimal changes, you could do:

```
Future<void> longRunningOperation1() async {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i += 1) {
    if (i % 10000000 == 0) {
      print('longRunningOperation1: $i');
      await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
    }
  }
}

Future<void> longRunningOperation2() async {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i += 1) {
    if (i % 10000000 == 0) {
      print('longRunningOperation2: $i');
      await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a wrapper to spawn slow operations into a separate `Isolate` and return a`Future`. It also allows to pass the function to run and some arguments as well.

````dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';

/// Example
///
/// ```
/// main() async {
///   String str;
///   str = await runAsync<String, String Function(String)>(sing, ["lalalala"]);
///   print(str);
///
///   str = await runAsync<String, Function>(song);
///   print(str);
/// }
/// 
/// String sing(String str) => "Singing: " + str;
/// String song() => "lololololo";
/// ```

Future<R> runAsync<R, F>(F func, [List<dynamic> parameters]) async {
  final receivePort = ReceivePort();
  await Isolate.spawn(asyncRunner, receivePort.sendPort);

  // The 'asyncRunner' isolate sends it's SendPort as the first message
  final sendPort = await receivePort.first;

  final responsePort = ReceivePort();
  sendPort.send([responsePort.sendPort, func, parameters ?? []]);
  final res = await responsePort.first;
  if (res is! R)
    return Future.error(res);
  else if (res == null) return null;
  return res as R;
}

// Isolate entry point
void asyncRunner(SendPort sendPort) async {
  // Open the ReceivePort for incoming messages
  final port = ReceivePort();

  // Notify our creator the port we listen to
  sendPort.send(port.sendPort);

  final msg = await port.first;

  // Execute
  final SendPort replyTo = msg[0];
  final Function myFunc = msg[1];
  final List<dynamic> parameters = msg[2] ?? [];

  try {
    switch (parameters.length) {
      case 0:
        replyTo.send(myFunc());
        break;
      case 1:
        replyTo.send(myFunc(parameters[0]));
        break;
      case 2:
        replyTo.send(myFunc(parameters[0], parameters[1]));
        break;
      case 3:
        replyTo.send(myFunc(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2]));
        break;
      case 4:
        replyTo.send(
            myFunc(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3]));
        break;
      case 5:
        replyTo.send(myFunc(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2],
            parameters[3], parameters[4]));
        break;
      default:
        replyTo.send(Exception("Unsupported argument length"));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    replyTo.send(Exception(err.toString()));
  }

  // Done
  port.close();
  Isolate.current.kill();
}
````

https://github.com/vocdoni/dvote-dart/blob/main/lib/util/asyncify.dart#L16