# CircularProgressIndicator is triggered not in time

Tags: flutter

There is a state class

```
class _SignUpFormState extends State<SignUpForm> {
  bool _isProcessing = false;
  ...
```

where in build method I have

```
_isProcessing ? CircularProgressIndicator() : SizedBox(),
```

_isProcessing is triggered in this func

```
void _submit() {
    setState(() {
      _isProcessing = true;
    });

    // doing something heavy that takes a while

    Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => TabPage(),
    ),
);
```

The problem is that `CircularProgressIndicator` is running for a very small amount of time right before navigating to other screen. Should not it run before a long term process like it is shown in the code above?

Comment: Post the code of your "heavy" thing

Comment: @Sidak this is enough 
`void main(){
    var j;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        j = i - 1;
    }
}`

Comment: And by Short time, how long does it run? like instant or its visible for a while

Comment: @Sidak it doesn't matter how long it takes because it just a sample to illustrate what's happening in the question code

Comment: you're missing the point here. The reason why I asked for the code is so that I can understand if it's async in nature or not. So if possible, put the actual code/a stripped down version that helps me understand the nature of the task better

Comment: @Sidak that code isn't async in nature. I use external pakage which methods isn't async. So what can we do in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213761/discussion-between-sidak-and-rozerro).

Answer (score 0):

your heavy thing is not async(because your method is not async) then it will not take time.

If you wan to show CircularProgressIndicator for a while then you can make your method async and add future delay.

Comment: That' interesting but how to make async method from synhronous method? That long term process is not return Future but just void.

Comment: if you make method async then it will not return Future objects. you can make method async in following way Future<void> _submit() async{

Comment: did you read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61738730/5829191
that said it's "Dart will attempt to run it synchronously anyway"

Comment: he is taking about that particular case, because that function is not use await for any process and it is not async method.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya, we don't know if the actual "heavy" code is async in the first place or not

Comment: @Sidak I think if heavy code is async then this method also should be async, right ? I also mention reason of my assumption in brackets in my answer.