# How to make actual calculation in Dart parallel?

Tags: dart, async-await, future

I have the following program:

```
main(){
  print("A");
  foo2();
  print("B");
}

void foo1()async {
  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++);
  print("X");
}

void foo2() async{
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  print("X");
  
}
```

When I use `foo2` in `main`, Dart behave like I want it to behave, it prints `A`, than `B` and some time later `X`:

```
A
B
X
```

But when I use the `foo1` function in `main`, it does no longer work that way. If i copy this in an online evaluator like [DartPad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/?) it first waits a little and than prints

```
A
X
B
```

How can I make `foo1` work like `foo2`? Of course, later I want to use something else than just `for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++);` but its quite like that a big calculation.

I want to know this, because in flutter tutorials, they always use something like `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));` to mimic a delay because of a big calcualtion - and than it always works out fine (like in `foo2`). But when I really try to make some calculations that take some time (like in `foo1`) it is no longer working.

Comment: This seems to be a pure dart question, not a flutter question.  I fixed the tags.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61737500/

Comment: And if you want to perform the calculation in *parallel* (not just concurrently), then you will need to do that work in a separate Dart isolate.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
main(){
  print("A");
  Future<void>(()=>foo2());
  print("B");
}
```

This prints

```
A
B
X
```